# Move drawing to any position in Word 2000

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2000

I'm using Word 2000 and I have problems with positioning drawings. There seems to be an invisible grid and a drawing's sides has to be on this grid. I found a way of resizing images to any size by using the "size" tab in the "drawing format" dialog box, but I can't put them anywhere where other than where their top left corner is on this kind of grid. This is very annoying since I would like to make a more complex drawing and superpose drawings. How can I place a drawing at any position and not just on the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I was using Word 2000, but if I remember correctly, the "Layout" tab did exist. Try selecting the "Tight" option, and see if that allows you to move things around freely. Alongside that, the link below may be helpful when you come to superimpose drawings:

[Sending Drawing Objects to the Back or Front - WordTips](http://word.tips.net/T001872_Sending_Drawing_Objects_to_the_Back_or_Front.html)

On a final note, Word 2000 will always be fine at word processing, but more recent versions of Word have significantly improved users ability to do things like this; it might be worth thinking about an upgrade, but that's totally up to you

Comment: If you go into the "advanced" button of the Layout tab, you can enter the exact position.